# No se muestra un Dialogo al hacer el show en Android Studio

Tags: android

Buenas comunidad. 
Tengo un método que saca un dialogo de confirmación, si pinchas en aceptar sale un cuadro de dialogo mientras se envian unos datos por `firebase`, primero saco el cuadro y luego envio los datos. El tema es que el cuadro no se muestra pero si que envian los datos, que es lo que se supone que va después. He creado una variable de la clase de `Dialog` para guardar el `AlertDialog` que devuelve el `builder` al hacer el `.show()` para poder hacer `dismiss()` del dialogo cuando se acabe de enviar todo. El problema es que el cuadro nunca se muestra. Espero que me podáis ayudar. Un saludo y gracias.

```
private void dialogoConfirmacion() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.informacion)
            .setMessage(R.string.infoIncidenciaEnviar)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.aceptar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    lanzarCuadro();

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancelar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                }
            });


    builder.create();
    builder.show();

}

private void lanzarCuadro(){

    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cuadro_carga_subir, null);
    tituloCuadro=view.findViewById(R.id.txt_titulo_cuadro_carga_subir);
    subtituloCuadro=view.findViewById(R.id.txt_texto_ayuda_cuadro_carga_subir);
    barraCuadro=view.findViewById(R.id.barra_cuadro_carga_subir);
    barraCuadro.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
    tituloCuadro.setText(R.string.subiendoImagenes);
    builder.setView(view);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.create();
    dialogo=builder.show();
    dialogo.create();
    dialogo.show();





    new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            enviarConfirmado();
        }
    }.run();


}
```

Comment: Hola Adrián, ¿Se produce un error? Agrega el error desplegado en el LogCat.

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys, no no se produce ningún error en el LogCat, lo único que no se muestra el dialogo

Comment: Si el dialogo que no se despliega es el de tu método "dialogoConfirmacion", entonces creo que en la parte de `builder.create();
    builder.show();` tendría que ir `AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();`

Comment: @JorgeRequez es una de las pruebas que hice también y tampoco se muestra